# How to resize an EPS file in Illustrator to fit a pixel size?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, vector, resize

I'm very new to Illustrator. Having used Photoshop all my life, vector art is something very new to me. I have this company logo in EPS format. I want to use AI to resize the image to a certain pixel size in order to fit properly on a website.
I've only drawn some trees and landscape using AI, doing this has me totally lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I actually figured it out myself. 
You can adjust the artboard size using the artboard tool, then go to File > Save for Web & Devices. There's a panel that allows you to adjust the export dimensions in pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution in this case would be to use Illustrator's “View->Pixel Preview” mode if applicable (I don't know which version you've got there). This way you'll have much greater control over final results, than by any form of automatic rasterization (e.g. “Save for Web”). Think of it as of manual “pixel perfext hinting”.

Also using “pixels” as “document units”, as Mark Edwards suggested, would be a good thing. It will make it possible to set artboard to exact needed size in pixels.

Of course “Save for Web” still would be useful, with its possibility to provide quick preview and optimization of resultant file.

TIP (mentioned in some comment here): you can scale objects proportionally by entering in info or transform panel their new width/height and confirming your value with “Ctrl/Command+Enter” combo.

As for the whole subject you can take a look at http://medialoot.com/blog/3-valuable-pixel-perfect-illustrator-techniques/ for more complete explanation with graphic examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can also adjust the individual image by using the Transform properties (Window-> Transform) or on the top toolbar. You can then copy-paste to Photoshop at the exact size you need.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do it, but I think this might be the easiest:

- Ensure Illustrator is working in pixels.
- You should probably also ensure you're working in RGB (this is for the web, right?)
- Select everything you want to scale.
- Look at the Info panel, and take note of the size.
- Work out the scale factor: new size / old size.
- Double click the scale tool and enter the scale you need.

If your logo is currently 500px wide and you want it to be 100px wide, then that's 100/500 = 0.2. "0.2" is 20%.

This is far more accurate than scaling by eye. When you're done, you may want to turn on pixel snapping and ensure things are nicely lined up.

Comment: Just FYI... you can do math functions in measurement fields. So you could enter 100/500 in the scale fields.

Comment: Actually you don't even have to calculate scale. In info panel, between width and height controls, there's a small “chain” icon. If it's “pressed”, each value entered to into one of the controls will cause the other to be set to a value which maintains scaled object proportions. E.g. width was 400 px, height 300 px. New width was 200 px, so new width is set to 150 px. Even if “chain” icon is “off” (the following reverses its setting temporarily) you can force this behavior by entering value and pressing Ctrl/Command+Enter.

Comment: Cancel that about “reversing” – my mistake :). The rest holds true.